# Preserve which page I was on before logging out Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to preserve which page I was on before logging out and be redirected to that same page and not a default homepage after login.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve it.

1. Save the page/route name in the database and retrieve it on login.
2. Save the page/route name in local storage and retrieve it on login.

In your login component then check if there was a value in local storage or database:

If **YES**: route to page you were on before login out.

```
this.router.navigate(['your page before logout']);
```

If **No**: route to the default page.